# Typoscript custom content get Media Image in Template

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

i want a custom Element that only render a image.
I have create a custom extension.

This is what i got:

ext_tables.php

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig('
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.common.elements {
    cce_teaser {
        icon = EXT:core/Resources/Public/Icons/T3Icons/content/content-image.svg
        title = Produkt Bild
        description = Hauptbild auf der Produktseite
        tt_content_defValues.CType = product_image
    }
}
mod.wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.common.show := addToList(cce_teaser)
');

$TCA['tt_content']['columns']['CType']['config']['items'][] =
  array(
    'Custom Content Elements',
    '--div--'
  );

$TCA['tt_content']['columns']['CType']['config']['items'][] =
  array(
    'Hauptbild auf der Produktseite',
    'product_image',
        \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extRelPath($_EXTKEY) . 'ext_icon.gif'
  );

$TCA['tt_content']['types']['product_image']['showitem'] = '
    --palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xml:palette.general;general,
    --palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xml:palette.header;header,
    --div--;Text,
    bodytext;Text;;richtext:rte_transform[flag=rte_enabled|mode=ts_css], rte_enabled;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xml:rte_enabled_formlabel,
    --div--;Bilder,
    image,
    --div--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xml:tabs.access,
    --palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xml:palette.visibility;visibility,
    --palette--;LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xml:palette.access;access,
';
```

That works i get:

[Custom Image Element in Backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YoJb.png)

2000_product_page.t3s

```
tt_content.product_image = COA
tt_content.product_image {
  10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
  10 {
    file = {$resDir}/Private/Templates/ProductDetailImage.html
    partialRootPath = {$resDir}/Private/Partials
    layoutRootPath = {$resDir}/Private/Layouts
  }
}
```

ProductDetailImage.html

```
<html xmlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers" xmlns:ce="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/FluidStyledContent/ViewHelpers" data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true">
<h1>Test</h1>

<f:debug>{data}</f:debug>
<!-- HOW CAN I GET THE IMAGE INFORMATIONS? SRC, TITLE, WITH, HEIGHT ... -->

</html>
```

The Template ProductDetailImage.html is rendered but i have no clue how to get the Image data.
Does someone know what i have to do? Pls help!

Thanks all for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your image upload field is configured correctly using FAL, since TYPO3 7.6 you can use processors in FLUIDTEMPLATE. To get the image data you can use a ViewHelper or those processors. Check out the FilesProcessor here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html

Comment: Hi Paul, thx for your answer!
Can you explain me more about "if your image upload field is configured correctly using FAL ???

Can u pls make a short example ?

Comment: Do you have a working "Upload / Select Files"-field inside your ContentObject? Does ist save selected files properly?
Your TCA is configured to display the field "image" and I'm currently not sure if this is field is still present in TYPO3 or has been renamed. But if you got a field for the image everything should be fine with it.

Comment: My solution :

`tt_content.product_show_image = COA
    tt_content.product_show_image {
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        file = {$resDir}/Private/Templates/ProductContentImage.html
        partialRootPath = {$resDir}/Private/Partials
        layoutRootPath = {$resDir}/Private/Layouts
        dataProcessing.10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
        dataProcessing.10 {
            references {
                table = tt_content
                fieldName = image
            }
            as = images
        }

    }
}`